# Property then doesn't exist on type void, although I am returning a Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function that gets a bot's inventory on the Frontend

```
  getBotInventory() {
    this.socket.emit('get bot inv');
    this.socket.on('bot inv', (botInventory) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (botInventory.error) {
          return reject(botInventory.error);
        }
        this.botInventory = botInventory;
        resolve(botInventory);
      });

    });
  }
```

As you can see, it returns a Promise.

When I try to call it

```
getBotInventory() {
    this.userService.getBotInventory().then(botInv..)
  }
```

I'm getting

> error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

Obviously it returns a `Promise`. Can anyone point out where the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be obvious for you, but it isn't for me.

Look at your function, cleaned of callbacks.

```
getBotInventory() {
  this.socket.emit('get bot inv');
  this.socket.on('bot inv', (botInventory) => {...});
}
```

I don't see any return statement there !

Comment: Got lost in the world of callbacks hell. Thanks!

Comment: No problem ! If you need help on how to handle that, feel free to ask !

Comment: ```

  getBotInventory() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.socket.emit('get bot inv');
      this.socket.on('bot inv', (botInventory) => {
        if (botInventory.error) {
          return reject(botInventory.error);
        }
        this.botInventory = botInventory;
        resolve(botInventory);
      });
    });
  }

```
got it working :)